# Paste a range over existing data without deleting it

Tags: excel, copy, paste

Hope I'm in the right place.

I have a spreadsheet which is around 8000 rows long and I need to paste a column of data from J to E.  Problem is that E already has some data in it which I want to retain.  The data in J is also partial and needs to be pasted into blank cells in E.

The result would be a complete list of data in E which is a combination of E's original data and the pasted data from J.

Thanks

Comment: Merge two arrays and return the result to the worksheet.

Comment: Copy range 1, go to range 2, right click top left destination cell and select `insert copied cells`, when prompted, choose `Shift Cells Right`

Comment: This question should rather go to superuser.com, since it does not seem to be about programming.

Comment: @iDevlop I don't think the procedure you described does this.

Comment: @ExcelHero: I tried before posting. If I find the time this w-e I'll capture it in a video. And it works also with full columns. And one can also use drag & drop, using the mouse + Ctrl + Shift

Answer (score 0):

Place the following routine in a standard code module and run it with the worksheet active:

```
Public Sub excelhero()
    Dim e&, j&, i&, v, vE, vJ
    With ActiveSheet
        e = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    ReDim vE(1 To e, 1 To 1)
    ReDim vJ(1 To j, 1 To 1)
    ReDim v(1 To Application.max(e, j), 1 To 1)
    vE = [e1].Resize(UBound(vE))
    vJ = [j1].Resize(UBound(vJ))
    For i = 1 To UBound(vE)
        v(i, 1) = vE(i, 1)
    Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(vJ)
        If Len(vJ(i, 1)) Then
            v(i, 1) = vJ(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    [e1].Resize(UBound(v)) = v
End Sub
```

The above will work for your specific columns. Here is a more generic version that will work for merging any two columns. It will also work for your scenario because columns E and J are set to be the columns it works with at the top. COLA_A values will not be overwritten, only COL_A empty cells will be.

```
Public Sub MergeColumns()
    Const COL_A = "E"   '<-- COL_A has priority.
    Const COL_B = "J"
    Dim cola&, colb&, i&, v, vA, vB
    With ActiveSheet
        cola = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_A).End(xlUp).Row
        colb = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_B).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    ReDim vA(1 To cola, 1 To 1)
    ReDim vB(1 To colb, 1 To 1)
    ReDim v(1 To Application.max(cola, colb), 1 To 1)
    vA = Range(COL_A & 1).Resize(UBound(vA))
    vB = Range(COL_B & 1).Resize(UBound(vB))
    For i = 1 To UBound(vA)
        v(i, 1) = vA(i, 1)
    Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(vB)
        If Len(vB(i, 1)) Then
            v(i, 1) = vB(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    Range(COL_A & 1).Resize(UBound(v)) = v
End Sub
```